# Is there better way to navigate in Android based on source fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

[image: fragments]

I have fragments  *S1*, *S2*, *P*, *D1*, and *D2*.

Both *S1* and *S2* have action leading to *P*. When I am in fragment *P* I can navigate to *D1* or *D2*.
When I came from *S1* I want to navigate to *D1*, but when I came from *S2* I want to go to *D2*.

**What is the best way to do navigate based on the source fragment?**.

I know I can use arguments for this, but it seems like a much more basic operation. I would expect some more clear and quicker solution (for example some method `getNameOfSource()`).

Comment: You can find in your backstack the previous fragment and based on that you can judge where to go next. Although using arguments is far more convenient than that I'd argue, but it is beyond the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via getting the entry from your Fragment Backstack, although you need to ensure you are providing some sort of `TAG` to them in the first place. You can simply use something like this then. Using arguments is still better I would say, but that is out of scope for this question

```kotlin
private fun getNameOfSource(): String? {
        val fm = supportFragmentManager
        val count = fm.backStackEntryCount
        return fm.getBackStackEntryAt(count - 2).name
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the fragment tag using this code:

```
public Fragment getSourceFragmentName() {
    // you need to check this because you need at least 2 fragments at the backstack
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() < 2) {
        return null;
    }
    
    String fragmentTag = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 2).getName();
    
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
}
```